# Made a change in Interface Builder, Xcode is not showing it

Tags: objective-c, xcode, textbox, interface-builder

So here is what my interface looks like at the moment:

[image: Start interface]

Here is what I have changed it to in Interface Builder:
[image: Desired interface]

This is what is shown after I run it in Xcode:
[image: Resulting interface]

Obviously the two programs are not communicating - if someone could point me in the right direction it would be great.

Thanks heaps!

Comment: I know it is silly to ask, but did you save the .xib file after you edited it?  If not, xcode will continue to load the most recent saved file.  If it is saved with the textField, however, we can try to work from there

Comment: Thanks, I did save it but I also changed the name of the file - which it didn't like (for obvious reasons lol) xD It is fixed now :3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If stuff isn't in sync, try cleaning your build.  *Product>Clean* should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks everyone, it seemed to be a combination of both.

First I did 'Clean All Targets', and then I built and ran it. It then told me that the nib it was trying to read wasn't there.

I realised that I had changed the name of the nib I was working on, and my program was expecting the old name.
After re-saving it as the old name, it now works! :)

Comment: Try removing application from iOS Simulator (or Device) - this is what helped me.

Comment: @Pavel: Maybe you're thinking of iOS programming, but the Mac doesn't have a simulator.  The app runs directly. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The programs communicate through the NIB/XIB files. Make sure you have saved your changes from Interface Builder before rebuilding in XCode (this does not happen automatically). Also double check that the file Interface Builder is editing is the exact same file (not a copy) of the one in your XCode project.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks everyone, it seemed to be a combination of both. First I did 'Clean All Targets', and then I built and ran it. It then told me that the nib it was trying to read wasn't there. I realised that I had changed the name of the nib I was working on, and my program was expecting the old name. After re-saving it as the old name, it now works! :)

Answer (score 0):

This happens if you rename a nib but forget to change name of nib name passed in to a ViewController in its `initWithNibName: bundle` initialiser.

For example. If I have a nib named `ViewOne.xib` which I'm passing in to a ViewController like this:

```
ExampleViewController *exampleViewController = [[ExampleViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewOne" bundle:nil];
```

And I change the name of the nib to `ViewTwo`, Xcode isn't smart enough to amend this reference in the initialiser, so now a xib that noi longer exists is being passed in to the ViewController. For reasons that I cannot fathom, despite the fact there is no longer a nib called `ViewOne.xib`, Xcode maintains some sort of ghost of the file and you won't get an error because of the missing nib. Cleaning and deleting derived data *did not get rid of this ghost reference, at least in my case.*

The fix is easy - just amend the nib name in the initialiser to your new name:

```
ExampleViewController *exampleViewController = [[ExampleViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewTwo" bundle:nil];
```