# make the new window default in cocoa app

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have 2 questions (beginners) about **cocoa** apps:

1. I have created new cocoa app. I created new class, `MSDMasterWindowController` and I checked the checkbox new **.xib** file to be created. I would like to make the new window to became default window. How can I do that?
2. Reason for trying this is that I can't find where to write the code for the default window (no .h and .m files for it) Can I create new class subclass of `NSWindowController`, and then somehow connect that class with the default **.xib**? What is the purpose of this window?

Any clarification about the above questions or link to some tutorials where this subject is explained will be deeply appreciated. I have downloaded the Window programming guide, and I am looking it currently.

Regards, John.

Comment: Is it a document based app? Your newly created app should have a window already if you didn't start with an empty project, but used one of the  templates.

Comment: No, it is not document based app. Newly created app do have window, and reason why i want to do this is explained in the second question

Comment: Recommended article: https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2013-04-05-windows-and-window-controllers.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each **XIB** has a file's owner which you can hook up to a custom class.  If you create a `NSWindowController` subclass, you can use that as the owner of a separate **XIB**.

The default window in a single-coordinator application ***can*** be placed in **MainMenu.xib**, which has `NSApplication` as the file's owner, though it's probably good practice to have a separate window controller for the main window, so you can control when it is displayed and hidden versus the `NSApp` default behaviour.

Similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23688840/login-xib-then-launch-mainmenu-xib-xcode-os-x/23690008#23690008).

You can have `applicationDidFinishLaunching` and other various app delegate methods display the window.  Or menu items in the main menu.   Methods vary, but perhaps you'll want to have a property in you app delegate instance that is an instance of your `NSWindowController` subclass.

```
self.wincon = [[MYCustomWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"MainWindow"];
[self.wincon showWindow:self];
```

... where "**MainWindow.xib**" would be the xib file with `MYCustomWindowController` as file's owner.

Comment: what should i type instead of .wincon?

Comment: Whatever matches the name of the @property you add to your app delegate class.

Comment: what type should that property be? any example?

Comment: "your nswindowcontroller subclass"

Comment: I get an error now "No visible interface for MSDMasterWindowController' declarers the selector makeKeyAndOrderFront...ugh...any idea?

Comment: yeah, I corrected that... use showWindow.  makeKeyAndOrderFront is  an NSWindow method.  So that would be `[self.wincon.window makeKeyAndOrderFront]` though that may only be necessary if you start adding other windows to your app.

Comment: Even that I add MainWindow in the window identity field, i get this message : [MSDMasterWindowController loadWindow]: failed to load window nib file 'MainWindow'. and the default window is loaded after that. What i am doing wrong now?

Comment: "MainWindow" corresponds to whatever the xib is named, for example "MainWindow.xib". Re: "the default window is loaded after that" -- If you have a window in mainMenu.xib, it's still going to be loaded.

Comment: I can't beleive it... I deleted the window, i confirmed the remove reference dialog, and i save, restart x code...I still get the same message, and still default window is loaded???!!! Restart Mac?

Comment: One of the answers [here??](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956907/made-a-change-in-interface-builder-xcode-is-not-showing-it)

Comment: Thanks for helping me....Yep, that did the trick...now i get the magificant error message: Unable to load nib file: MainMenu, exiting....what i did this time?

Comment: MainMenu.xib is loaded by NSApplicationMain() in main.m because it's set as the main nib file in the app's info.plist.   So it has already been loaded.   You said you had created a new xib?  And set the file's owner to your MSDMasterWindowController?  Call that in initWithWindowNibName...

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I have to go. I will give it another try tomorrow...here is now 5:52, and i have to wake up in 7:30....see you.